# Event triggering once across all cache

Tags: ignite

Hi I'm newbie in ignite.

In my case, I use three caches

I wanna knew when rebalancing is occured, so I registered event listener.

but because I have three caches, so listener triggered 3times when new node joined or node left.

can I triggering only once? I mean, I wanna trigger rebalancing event once across all caches.

Comment: Why exactly do you need this? What is the business use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `CacheRebalancingEvent` does not contain `topologyVersion` so your best shot is comparing `((CacheRebalancingEvent)event).discoveryTimestamp()`. If they're equal, you can reasonably expect that it's the same rebalancing.